# ng-bootstrap example calling method from component

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

angular2 [ng-bootstrap drop down](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown) dropdown component

Can some one help me to find out how can i bind angular2 component with dropdown and call open or close method..

they don't have much documentation.

Answer (score 17):

You can use ViewChild decorator. In parent component it should look something like that:

```
import 'ViewChild' from '@angular/core'
import 'NgbDropdown' from '...';

[...]

export class ParentComponent {
  @ViewChild(NgbDropdown)
  private dropdown: NgbDropdown;

  closeDropdown() {
    this.dropdown.close();
  }
}
```

You can read more about ViewChild in official documentation: [Component Interaction | ViewChild](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-view-child).

Comment: if there are multiple dropdown on the page which one it is going to connect with ?

Comment: current bootstrap version import 'NgbDropdown' from '...';  you can't import any of the components. i have reported the issue will resolve in alpha 6

Comment: This needs more upvotes. Nice, clean, angular solution.

Answer (score 14):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to use an exported instance of the `NgbDropdown` directive. It can be done as follows (notice `#myDrop="ngbDropdown"`):

```
<div ngbDropdown #myDrop="ngbDropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu3" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
    <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

As soon as you do the above you can invoke documented (https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown) methods on the `NgbDropdown` directive instance. The available methods are: `open`, `close`, `toggle` and `isOpen`. You can invoke them as follows (example to open a dropdown from "outside"):

```
<button (click)="myDrop.open()">
```

Comment: thanks, can i also use myDrop reference to call open from component class ?

Comment: Yes, but you would have to pass it as an argument to a method call, ex.: `doSthFromAComponent(myDrop)`. And of course you can use the other answer: query for the dropdown instance from the component code - that way you don't need to go through a template.

Comment: i tried your answers, myDrop was not empty when i print it out on console, but calling open method didn't do any thing..

Comment: Causes test failure in Angular 6

Answer (score 6):

> HTML

```
<div ngbDropdown #myDrop="ngbDropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu3" 
      ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
      <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="closeDropdown()">Close Dropdown</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

> Angular

**make sure to import ViewChild and NgbDropdown**

```
import { NgbDropdown } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('myDrop', { static: true }) myDrop: NgbDropdown;

closeDropdown() {
   this.myDrop.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried the above and it did not seem to do anything, so i did some trial and error and found why when i called `myDrop.open()` nothing happened. You must add `[autoClose]="false"` to your the element having your dropdown reference.

```
<div ngbDropdown #myDrop="ngbDropdown" [autoClose]="false">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownMenu3" ngbDropdownToggle>Toggle</button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu3">
    <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
    <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
  </div>
</div

 //Somewhere else
<button (click)="myDrop.open()"> // or pass the reference as a parameter to call it 
                                    in a function.
```

Comment: You have typo in [autoclose] code, must be [autoClose] as you mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass the ngbDropdown instance into another component, as said above, define that instance as a template reference variable `#myDrop="ngbDropdown"`, then declare a property on the component you want to access that dropdown instance from with the Input decorator, like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `<button (click)=closeMyDrop()">Close myDrop</button>`
})
export class MyComponent {
    @Input() myDrop;
    closeMyDrop(){
       this.myDrop.close();
    }
}
```

Then in the parent component, where you use the child component, define the property of `myDrop` to the template reference variable, like:

```
<my-component [myDrop]="myDrop"></my-component>
```

[Angular 2 Documentation for template reference variables](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ref-vars)

[Angular 2 Documentation for passing data from parent to child with input binding](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child)

Comment: Btw, in the child component, you'll need to import `Input` from `@angular/core`